# Google Map SDK unreasonable amount of memory used when using markers

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7

I have a huge project, that has dozens of screens.

I had to include google maps into the project and show some markers on it.
The maximum number of markers is around 600, spread all over the town.

When I call this mapView, it increases memory consumption from 19 to 240mb. This is not reasonable at all, the app starts flooding with memory warnings and crashes soon.

What can I do to fix that?

iOS version is 7.1 and Google Maps SDK is 1.8.1

Comment: Hey man, didn't really think it was worth an answer as it's just a link but have you tried 'fusion tables'- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944585/adding-thousands-of-markers-google-map-api-v3

Comment: are all of your markers always on screen?

Comment: You should try clustering and only show individual markers when the zoom levels are high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each marker on Google Maps view has a bitmap. Adding marker creates a new bitmap for it.
I believe you have a limited types of markers and this, can share the bitmap along them.

Another strategy could be combining close markers into one metamarker and then, while user zoom-in - expand this group.

Good luck.